# Why is comma separator returning me a comma once I print it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, variables, separator

I'm trying to print a text once all evaluation is done saying: 'This list contains x numbers.
I tried to use both '+' and ',' to separate the string from the the variable, the problem is that when I try to use '+' as separator it displays a message saying: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.
Also, if I try to use ',' as separator I get another ',' at the end of my printed message.
I want this ',' to separate only in the code, I don't want it to show in the printed message.

I tried to replace both separators, also tried to find for answers on google. This is my third day learning so I just don't know exactly how to search for this kind of information. All information I found couldn't clarify what I should do to solve this problem the way I wanted.

```
print('Number of elements: ', *(colection), sep = ', ')
```

What do the message looks like now?

```
Numbers in the list: , 1, 2, 3
```

The final look I want it to have:

```
Numbers in the list: 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: `print('Number of elements: ', *(colection), sep = ', ')` can't possibly print `Numbers in the list: , 1, 2, 3`. Please be consistent, and also give a [mcve].

Comment: @MarkMeyer The point is that `'Number of elements: '` and `'Numbers in the list: '` are different strings.

Comment: @JohnColeman ha! Yes `print()` doesn't do that yet!

Answer (score 2):

When printing with a separator, each element printed is separated, including the initial tag line.

Assuming `colection`is a list of numbers, you can just use two prints and suppress the new line on the first one:

```
colection = [1,2,3]
print('Números da coleção: ',end='')
print(*colection,sep=', ')
```

Output:

```
Números da coleção: 1, 2, 3
```

Answer (score 1):

When you expand `print('Number of elements: ', *(colection), sep = ', ')`, what you actually are evaluating is `print('Number of elements: ', 1, 2, 3, sep = ', ')`.

What that means is that you have 4 elements and 3 commas. One of the commas is between the first string and the `1`.

I think what you want is to not use the separator argument in print, but instead use `', '.join(colection)`, for example like this:

```
print('Number of elements: ', ', '.join([str(i) for i in colection]))
```

Comment: If `colection` is a list of numbers, you'll probably need to turn them into strings before calling `join`.

Comment: Yep, forgot about that for a sec ;) It's changed now.

Comment: Also, `', '.join([str(i) for i in colection])` can be replaced by the simpler `', '.join(str(i) for i in colection)` since `.join()` can be fed a generator expression directly. Still, +1 for a good answer.

Comment: Got it ;) still a little new to python